# Convert RGB to Grayscale in bare C

Tags: c, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I am applying a basic tutorial on image processing in C and I am having problems with this program to convert RGB into grayscale but the output pic is somehow corrupted and although the code runs with no errors, and I cant put my hands on the problem. The code is below.

```
FILE *fIn = fopen("tiger.bmp","rb");                    //Input File name
FILE *fOut = fopen("tiger_gray.bmp","wb");              //Output File name

int i,j,y;
unsigned char byte[54];

if(fIn==NULL)   
{
    printf("File does not exist.\n");
}

for(i=0;i<54;i++)               //read the 54 byte header from fIn
{
    byte[i] = getc(fIn);
}

fwrite(byte,sizeof(unsigned char),54,fOut);         //write the header back
// extract image height, width and bit Depth from image Header
int height = *(int*)&byte[18];
int width = *(int*)&byte[22];
int bitDepth = *(int*)&byte[28];

printf("width: %d\n",width);
printf("height: %d\n",height );

int size = height*width;                        

unsigned char buffer[size][3];              //to store the image data


for(i=0;i<size;i++)                                         //RGB to gray
{
    y=0;
    buffer[i][2]=getc(fIn);                                 //blue
    buffer[i][1]=getc(fIn);                                 //green
    buffer[i][0]=getc(fIn);                                 //red

    y=(buffer[i][0]*0.3) + (buffer[i][1]*0.59)  + (buffer[i][2]*0.11);          //conversion formula of rgb to gray

    putc(y,fOut);
    putc(y,fOut);
    putc(y,fOut);
}

fclose(fOut);
fclose(fIn);
```

Comment: Please turn that into a [mcve] and explain/show what "somehow corrupted" means.

Comment: `getc()` I doubt to be the appropriate function to read binary data from a picture. Read the spec. Prefer to read and write binary into a buffer.

Comment: are you sure that is the correct way to read the header? I am getting a negative value for `height` with a `jpeg` image?

Comment: You're not paying any attention to the fact that each line of a bitmap must be padded to a multiple of 4 bytes.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi This is BMP specific code so it wouldn't work for a JPG. In a BMP file a negative height means the pixels are stored right side up versus upside down.

Comment: I tried and your code is working great.

Comment: You may want to jump to the flose calls, if the file read-error has occured.

Comment: If the picutre is big, you are allocating a lot of memory on the stack.
But: you do not need the two-dimensional array at all, because you write directly to the output file.
Just take three variable red, green, blue and calc the luminance y.

Comment: If the code is running fine at "Francesco Boi", it can actually be a stack problem. Just get rid of the buffer[size][3].

Comment: If you use `fwrite` for writing, why don’t you use `fread` for reading?

Comment: The strange thing is that it worked fine on some other pcs as well. Thank you all for the comments, I appreciate all the feedback since I am still learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two major problems in your code.

1. You had the width and height reversed.
2. You were not accounting for
   the required padding at the end of every row to make it a multiple
   of 4 bytes.

You were also allocating a large buffer that you did not need based on how the rest of the code was written. Generally I'd prefer to read/process either one full row at a time or even the full image at once, but to do that you want to use malloc or calloc because the data may be larger than the available stack. In this case, to keep things simple, I just process one pixel at a time.

I also got rid of getc/putc because I prefer fread/fwrite and you're never really dealing with 1 byte at a time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fIn = fopen("tiger.bmp", "rb");
    FILE *fOut = fopen("tiger_gray.bmp", "wb");
    if (!fIn || !fOut)
    {
        printf("File error.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned char header[54];
    fread(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fIn);
    fwrite(header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, fOut);

    int width = *(int*)&header[18];
    int height = abs(*(int*)&header[22]);
    int stride = (width * 3 + 3) & ~3;
    int padding = stride - width * 3;

    printf("width: %d (%d)\n", width, width * 3);
    printf("height: %d\n", height);
    printf("stride: %d\n", stride);
    printf("padding: %d\n", padding);

    unsigned char pixel[3];
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            fread(pixel, 3, 1, fIn);
            unsigned char gray = pixel[0] * 0.3 + pixel[1] * 0.58 + pixel[2] * 0.11;
            memset(pixel, gray, sizeof(pixel));
            fwrite(&pixel, 3, 1, fOut);
        }
        fread(pixel, padding, 1, fIn);
        fwrite(pixel, padding, 1, fOut);
    }
    fclose(fOut);
    fclose(fIn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked fine for me now. I even got a better result with just getting an average of the rgb values instead of using the equation. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Fwrite after memset pixel is 'buggy'

Comment: How is it 'buggy'? Can you explain?